# how to set coordinates of terminal like I do in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Using Ubuntu terminal for my c++ application.
Need to open the terminal on user defined coordinates
(if x 100, y 50, it opens on 100,50)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--geometry` flag for this. For example:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 80x24+100+50
```

The window will be 80 columns wide, 24 rows tall, and have its top-left corner at X position 100 and Y position 50.

Comment: what if I have second monitor and want to position terminal here?

Comment: Add the width of your first monitor to the horizontal coordinate. If your first monitor is 1600 pixels wide, X position 1700 will be 100 pixels into the other monitor.